# How to take those big side way jumps in super meat boy?

Tags: super-meat-boy

I'm somewhat stuck in the last but one level (Level 6-5 "Omega") of Super Meat Boy. I'm pretty sure I've taken similar jumps throughout the game before, but this jump is near the end of the level, and I haven't got a clue what magical key combination I should press in order to fly away that far from the side, and back again over the saw blade.

[image: difficult jump]

Maybe I should zig-zag up, bouncing back from the platform where SMB is standing (uncomfortably) on?

Comment: Is this level 6-5? I'm stuck in this level too but I haven't been able to get that far. Have you tried jumping below the wheel and then doing a regular walljump up, just like you have to do at the beginning with that other vertical wheel.

Comment: @badp: Yes, it's 6-5. The regular walljump up doesn't work, it doesn't clear far enough from the right. You just jump straight into the saw.

Comment: It is possible, but apparently difficult: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GT_a0dcdWac

Comment: Looks like once he's cleared it vertically, he uses shift to clear it horizontally too.

Comment: The regular walljump *does* work - I did it several times when trying to speedrun this level.  I wish I had read this thread first, though; I never even considered simply jumping across -_-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's certainly *possible* to do a big wall jump like that (you'll need to in some of world 7), in this particular instance, you don't need to do a vertical jump at all -- the sawblade can be cleared with a horizontal jump from the platform to the left. See this video for a demonstration:

or, pictorially, the yellow path:

[image]

Comment: .... world 7? :O I figured I would finish this thing today.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Sorry! :P World 7 is quite the doozy to boot. (And don't get me started on the Dark World)

Comment: K, this worked! So much easier.